# How to remove the footer record in csv using UTIL_FILE operation in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, csv, oracle11g

We are reading a csv file through Oracle Procedure having UTIL_FILE operation and have successfully ignored the header part, but we are not able to remove / bypass / ignore the footer part.

Comment: What logic did you use to skip the header on the file?  Does the footer have a particular format, or do you know it's always the last tine of the file?

Comment: Please show or describe file format, please also post code you already have. It is possible to ignore some part sofe file but you need to know how to recognise the footer.